# Is that possible in vmess to have multiple accounts with the same configuration file?

Tags: networking, vpn

I ran a `v2ray` server with `vmess` protocol, and I want to share that with some people but the issue is currently there's one UUID and so if I give it to one person he can share it with many people.

I read https://www.v2ray.com/en/configuration/api.html docs, even the API section but did not find anyway for this.

Is that possible? Or even is it possible to connect v2ray to an accounting service to manage accounts?

My current OS is Ubuntu if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple accounts with the same configuration but different UUIDs. here's how you should config it on vmess configuration:

```
 "clients": [
    {
      "id": "SOME UUID ID",
      "level": 0,
      "alterId": 0,
      "email": "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "27848739-7e62-4138-9fd3-098a63964b6b",
      "level": 0,
      "alterId": 0,
      "email": "user2@v2ray.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "27848739-7e62-4138-9fd3-098a63964b6b",
      "level": 0,
      "alterId": 0,
      "email": "user3@v2ray.com"
    }
  ],
```

and on the client configuration, you just change the UUID and your client will only have access to the account you gave them.

Note that, you can't limit the users with concurrent connections. you can limit them by giving them traffic and writing a script with NodeJS, Python or etc. so if the user used the exceeded the limit you remove them from the JSON config file and restart the server.

And v2ray doesn't have a good tool for getting used traffic and it's annoying to get traffic. anyway here's the doc: https://www.v2ray.com/en/configuration/stats.html

I suggest you use [XRay-Core](https://github.com/XTLS/Xray-core/issues/977) as in it gives you JSON format output for traffic usage.

Another option is to use the [X-UI](https://seakfind.github.io/2021/10/10/X-UI/) which is a panel that allows you create separate inbound for each user with limited traffic and subscription time.